# Error en CentOS 7: Failed to start Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, centos7

Tengo un servidor en el cual tengo el servicio de *SQL* activo, el servidor funcionaba bien, podíamos entrar a la base de datos, pero teníamos un problema, se nos había extraviado la contraseña `root` de ese servidor, restablecimos la contraseña del servidor y pudimos entrar, pero no levantaba el servicio de *SQL*.

Después de días logramos encontrar la contraseña, y bueno, devolvimos la contraseña a como estaba antes, pero el error con el servicio de *SQL* sigue.

> Failed to start Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine

Mi servidor es un *CentOS 7*, en internet vi que mencionaban la memoria, pero este no es el caso porque como digo, antes funcionaba bien y además el servidor tiene bastante memoria.

Comment: Y cuál es el error que sale al intentar levantar el servicio, normalmente el sistema muestra un detalle del error.

Comment: Cuando le doy  systemctl status mssql-server -l  me sale
loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since mar  
     Docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
  Process: 2738 ExecStart=/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr (code=killed, signal=ABRT)  Main PID: 2738 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for mssql-server.service
 systemd[1]: Failed to start Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
 systemd[1]: Unit mssql-server.service entered failed state.

Comment: si usas el comando `journalctl -u mssql-server.service -b` quizás te de más info sobre tu problema, a primera vista parece la memoria aunque ya dijiste que no es posible, quizás sea otra cosa relacionado también al arranque del servicio

Comment: encontre este error Error: The evaluation period has expired.
he buscado en internet, hice los pasos pero sigo con el error

Comment: Deberían cambiar la versión a una `express` o `developer` si quieren seguir probando con MS SQL, así no tendrán problemas con periodos de prueba.